# Как изменить SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES у уже созданной директории

Tags: c, winapi

К примеру так я могу создать директорию, но затем мне нужно изменить её атрибуты, для простоты я хотел бы к примеру создать обычную папку, а затем прикрутить ей DACL который использую в методе CreateMyDACL.

```
BOOL CreateMyDACL(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES * pSA)
{
    if (NULL == pSA)
        return FALSE;

    return ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(
        L"D:(A;OICI;GR;;;AU)",
        SDDL_REVISION_1,
        &(pSA->lpSecurityDescriptor),
        NULL);
}

void create_folder()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  sa;

    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    if (!CreateMyDACL(&sa))
    {
        printf("Failed CreateMyDACL\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (0 == CreateDirectory(L"D:\\MyFolder", &sa))
    {
        printf("Failed CreateDirectory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (NULL != LocalFree(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor))
    {
        printf("Failed LocalFree\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: от имени администратора запускайте программу

Comment: @helldrg Не вы не так поняли, этот код рабочий, но он присваивает атрибуты на этапе создания, а я к примеру просто создам папку без атрибутов, а атрибуты хочу присвоить несколько позже. То, что тут нужны администраторские права я знаю))

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DACL тут есть пример программы и все очень хорошо расписано. Будут вопросы задавайте

Comment: @helldrg Не увидел там в каком моменте я сам могу выбрать какой именно дескриптор мне туда вставить  "D:(A;OICI;GR;;;AU)"

Comment: используя SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES и  "D:(A;OICI;GR;;;AU)" я не могу подсказать как изменять элементы DACL. Может быть кто то другой подскажет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, нашел у себя подходящий кусочек в старых завалах. Похоже, это как раз то, что вам нужно.

```
void ChangeSecurity(LPCWSTR path) {
  HINSTANCE hAdvApi;
  DWORD (STDAPICALLTYPE * pSetNamedSecurityInfo)(LPWSTR pObjectName, SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType, SECURITY_INFORMATION SecurityInfo, PSID psidOwner, PSID psidGroup, PACL pDacl, PACL pSacl);
  PACL pDacl;
  DWORD dr;

  try {
    pDacl = CreateACL();
    hAdvApi = ::LoadLibrary(_TEXT("AdvApi32.dll"));
    if (!hAdvApi) throw sys_error();
    (FARPROC&)pSetNamedSecurityInfo = ::GetProcAddress(hAdvApi, "SetNamedSecurityInfoW");
    if (!pSetNamedSecurityInfo) throw sys_error();
    dr = pSetNamedSecurityInfo(const_cast<LPWSTR>(path), SE_FILE_OBJECT,
            DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            NULL, NULL, pDacl, NULL);
    ::LocalFree(pDacl);
    ::FreeLibrary(hAdvApi);
    if (dr != ERROR_SUCCESS) throw sys_error(dr);
  }
  catch (...) { }
}
```

Не стал приводить реализацию класса `sys_error` - назначение его очевидно, и вы скорее всего замените эти вызовы чем-нибудь своим.